# Stripe.net nuget package doesn't recognize json.net 9.0.1

Tags: json.net, stripe.net

I'm trying to install the Stripe.net 6.12.0 nuget package in my project. It has a dependency on the Json.NET 9.0.1 nuget package which I have installed, but when I go to install stripe.net, visual studio gives me the error message: "Stripe.NET already has a dependency defined for"Newtonsoft.Json'. What do I have to do to install Stripe.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was not obvious from the error message, but the solution was simply to upgrade Nuget. Was using 2.8.xxx and upgraded to the latest which is 2.12.xxx. Restarted. Fixed the problem.

Comment: So I think this means that stripe.net won't work on VS2012 and down because you can't get Nuget higher than 2.8 until VS2013. #beware